# How to keep Apple Photos library and file system in sync?

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app

Apple Photos has a setting to disable "Importing: Copy items to the Photos library". However, this does not prevent getting the library async with the file system if you delete a picture either in the library or on the file system since Apple Photos still keeps thumbnails.

How can this be prevented or how can a manual sync be triggered?
If this is not possible, what are potential alternatives?

Comment: The alternative is to copy everything into your library and use that as your source of truth. Photos keeps all the originals unmodified in your photo library folder, which you can access (although the file names will not be included). You do not need a Mac or Photos to recover the original images from the Photo Library file, if that's what you're worried about.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, by switching off Copy to Library, you're telling it you are going to control everything manually - ie you have switched off any sync.

File menu > Consolidate… will switch 'sync' back on - but I think it will do it by copying everything to the Library, not by just checking sync.

[image]

I cannot test as I keep all my general photos in the library already. My 'pro' work I keep entirely outside the Apple Photos structure & only ever drop small jpgs into Photos.